# Launch to other application

Tags: c#, uwp, protocols

I have a button that when clicked will open other apps (if you already have the app) or toward the windows store (if it did not have the app). But I have a problem, that is: when I have the application and clicking the button displays only the splash screen only and cannot open the application.

XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="miBtn" Width="50" Height="50" Margin="25,0,0,0" Click="miBtn_Click" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
                            <Button.Background>
                                <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="image/new (3.0)/menu/menu bawah/MI-ikon-200.png"/>
                            </Button.Background>
                        </Button>
```

Code:

```
private async void miBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
            options.PreferredApplicationPackageFamilyName = "MahoniGlobalPT.MajalahIndonesia_rm0rfdtcrak1p";
            options.PreferredApplicationDisplayName = "Majalah Indonesia";

            // Launch the URI and pass in the recommended app 
            var uriMI = new Uri("mi1:");
            // in case the user has no apps installed to handle the URI
            var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uriMI, options);
        }
```

How to handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I have the application and clicking the button displays only the splash screen only and cannot open the application.

When you are opening an App using Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync. **The `OnLaunchedMethod` of target App inside `App.xaml.cs` won't be triggered.** So, there won't be a root Frame created for target App. Thus, you can see splash screen only.

To solve the problem, you need to manually create root Frame of target App. You can achieve this in [Application.OnActivated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.application.onactivated.aspx): Open your target App and inside App.xaml.cs and add the following codes:

```
private Frame CreateRootFrame()
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

    // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
    // just ensure that the window is active
    if (rootFrame == null)
    {
        // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
        rootFrame = new Frame();

        // Set the default language
        rootFrame.Language = Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.Languages[0];
        rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

        // Place the frame in the current Window
        Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
    }

    return rootFrame;
}
```

**Update:** The process of creating Frame should be in `OnActivated` method:

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    var rootFrame = CreateRootFrame();
    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));//here navigate to typeof(YourPageName)
    Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

Comment: I've tried adding the code above on App.xaml.cs, but still it only displays a splash screen alone

Comment: yes, i add the code to the target app and run the app

Comment: Could you share a basic sample of the target App?

Comment: Here is the basic sample of the target app: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Auqiv8Ukng7U7TOt3HO4XCLlp_Qn

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake,[Application.OnActivated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.application.onactivated.aspx) should be applied in App.xaml.cs, not `OnShareTargetActivated`. I've updated my answer, please have a check :)

Answer (score 0):

This Sample will be helpful for you, Click [How to launch an UWP app from another app](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-launch-an-UWP-app-5abfa878).

In your launched app, you need to config `package.appxmanifest`. below XML is the core configuration.

```
<Package> 
  <Applications> 
    <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="CSReceiveUri.App"> 
      <Extensions> 
        <uap:Extension Category="windows.protocol"> 
          <uap:Protocol Name="test-launchmainpage"> 
            <uap:DisplayName>test-launchmainpage</uap:DisplayName> 
          </uap:Protocol> 
        </uap:Extension> 
        <uap:Extension Category="windows.protocol"> 
          <uap:Protocol Name="test-launchpage1"> 
            <uap:DisplayName>test-launchpage1</uap:DisplayName> 
          </uap:Protocol> 
        </uap:Extension> 
      </Extensions> 
    </Application> 
  </Applications> 
</Package>
```

In the app.cs of launched app, you need override `OnActivated` event handler, like this:

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            rootFrame = new Frame();
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
            rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;
        }

        //because this is in (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol) block, so the type of args must is ProtocolActivatedEventArgs
        //convert to type ProtocolActivatedEventArgs, and we can visit Uri property in type ProtocolActivatedEventArgs
        var protocolEventArgs = args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;
        //Switch to a view by Scheme
        switch (protocolEventArgs.Uri.Scheme)
        {
            //under case is the protocol scheme in the Package.appxmanifest
            //Navigate to target page with Uri as parameter
            case "test-launchmainpage":
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), protocolEventArgs.Uri);
                break;
            case "test-launchpage1":
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(Page1), protocolEventArgs.Uri);
                break;
            default:
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), protocolEventArgs.Uri);
                break;
        }

        //start show UI
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
}
```